# How to Inject Moshi/Gson in Room TypeConvertors using Hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am trying out hilt and i want to inject moshi for serializing and deserializing.

Here's a code [sample](https://github.com/skydoves/Pokedex/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/skydoves/pokedex/persistence/converters/InfoTypeConverter.kt) from a github Repo which is not using di:

```
open class InfoTypeConverter {

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build() //not using dependency injection

  @TypeConverter
  fun fromString(value: String): PokemonInfo.Type? {
    val adapter: JsonAdapter<PokemonInfo.Type> = moshi.adapter(PokemonInfo.Type::class.java)
    return adapter.fromJson(value)
  }

  @TypeConverter
  fun fromInfoType(type: PokemonInfo.Type): String {
    val adapter: JsonAdapter<PokemonInfo.Type> = moshi.adapter(PokemonInfo.Type::class.java)
    return adapter.toJson(type)
  }
}
```

I am Trying out random stuff to field inject this like annotaion with @AndroidEntryPoint/@EntryPoint and obviously it's not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Including `Moshi` in the Hilt dependency graph is as simple as adding this class:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object DataModule {

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
      return Moshi.Builder().build()
  }
}
```

---

`@TypeConverters` are for the `Room` database. If you want to use the Moshi from Hilt for them, you will have to try a bit. One way of doing this is:

1. Put `@TypeConverter` functions in a static context (`object` declaration) with an initializer

```
object InfoTypeConverter {

    private lateinit var moshi: Moshi

    fun initialize(moshi: Moshi){
        this.moshi = moshi
    }

    
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String): PokemonInfo.Type? {
      val adapter: JsonAdapter<PokemonInfo.Type> = moshi.adapter(PokemonInfo.Type::class.java)
      return adapter.fromJson(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromInfoType(type: PokemonInfo.Type): String {
      val adapter: JsonAdapter<PokemonInfo.Type> = moshi.adapter(PokemonInfo.Type::class.java)
      return adapter.toJson(type)
    }
}
```

2. Initialize `InfoTypeConverter` before creating your RoomDatabase (here using the same module for the purpose):

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object DataModule {

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
      return Moshi.Builder().build()
  }

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  fun provideRoomDatabase(moshi: Moshi): YourDatabase {
      InfoTypeConverter.initialize(moshi)
      val yourDatabase: YourDatabase = /* create your room database here */
      return yourDatabase
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! But, isn't there any other way like field injection? I mean,i have used koin for di, In that you can inject moshi like `val moshi: Moshi by Inject()`

Comment: 1. But you had to also initialize `Moshi` somewhere else, right? You can also now inject moshi wherever you want with `@Inject`. This whole initializing craziness that you have to do here is because of the way Room works with `TypeConverters`.
2. That's just one way of doing things. You could also create an `EntryPoint` for the `InfoTypeConverter` and field-inject Moshi there, but for me the approach I suggested in the answer is cleaner.
3. Koin and Dagger/Hilt are two very different concepts, so naturally there are differences.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank You for the explanation.